# When is a background image loaded in a print stylesheet?

Tags: css, printing

Let's say I have a rule in my print stylesheet that includes a background-image.

```css
div.content {
    background-image:url("abc.jpg");
}
```

Will the graphic (abc.jpg) download as soon as the page is loaded in the browser or will it  download only when the print function is activated?

Answer (score 1):

The print stylesheet itself will be downloaded on page load, but the image will only be downloaded when the print function is activated and the print stylesheet actually used.

Note that the background image may not actually be applied, because browsers do not print background images by default (although depending on the browser this may be toggled in the user preferences). As a result, you may potentially be wasting HTTP requests by including background images in your print styles.